# Using "later" as a connector in formulas like "to, later, make a new proposal"

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, construction

I was wondering if it would be correct to use later in a construction like this:

> "We will study the domain of interest to, *later*, propose several improvements"

The idea is to write a sentence like "*We will study the domain of interest and propose several improvements afterwards*", but I'd like to know if a construction like the one in the first sentence is correct to use, because it feels familiar to some formulas you can use in Spanish and I'd like to know if I can use it.

Comment: You study then propose. Why do you need the *later* or *afterwards* at all? Of course it's later. The position and the commas call undue attention to the little word *later*.

Comment: When the sequence is important, you could use also use *subsequently*.

Comment: It's not a connector, quite the opposite, it's parenthetical.

Comment: @YosefBaskin it's a personal preference to make emphasis, and to know if it's correct

Comment: It doesn't sound natural to me, no.

Comment: @YosefBaskin and is it grammatically correct?

Comment: @DjinTonic as in "to subsequently propose several improvements"?

Comment: Unless you need to emphasize that the improvements won't be relatively  soon, you could  keep "We will study the domain of interest and (then) propose several improvements." Otherwise "We will study the domain of interest and subsequently propose several improvements." I don't think the "to" is needed to emphasize "for the purpose of" As is, the "later" is in an unidiomatic position. The sequence is implicit in the original.

Comment: No, you placed *later*, with unnecessary commas, in a position that is not grammatically correct. English does say the *below* list, I will *earlier* preheat the oven, She will *Monday* go shopping.